# getting specific process using linux command

Tags: linux, bash, process, ps

i have this command:

```
ps -C java -o pid=,%mem=,vsz=,%cpu=,command=
```

which produce the following output:

```
2982  5.0 12313368 11.3 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -Dname=kafka_broker -Xmx1G -Xms384M -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:Initia
  3296  0.7 4150868 0.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -Dname=zookeeper -Xmx512M -Xms512M -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:Initiatin
  9067  3.7 5889540 15.7 java -Dname=eq_engine -Dlogback.configurationFile=/eq/equalum/eql-server-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/conf/engine_logback.xml -Xmx2G -Xms256M -Xss384K -server -Djava.security
  9308  5.1 4895240 1.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -cp /eq/equalum/eql-server-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/eql-job-server/lib/*:/eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-ha
  9378  2.2 4745848 0.2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -cp /eq/equalum/eql-server-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/eql-job-server/lib/*:/eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-ha
  9379  2.1 4745848 0.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -cp /eq/equalum/eql-server-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/eql-job-server/lib/*:/eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-ha
  9380  2.2 4745848 0.2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -cp /eq/equalum/eql-server-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/eql-job-server/lib/*:/eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-ha
  9387  2.1 4745848 0.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -cp /eq/equalum/eql-server-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/eql-job-server/lib/*:/eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-ha
  9418  2.0 4745848 0.2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -cp /eq/equalum/eql-server-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/eql-job-server/lib/*:/eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-ha
  9421  1.9 4745848 0.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -cp /eq/equalum/eql-server-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/eql-job-server/lib/*:/eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-ha
  9448  2.0 4680312 0.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -cp /eq/equalum/eql-server-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/eql-job-server/lib/*:/eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-ha
  9853  3.2 5800672 1.5 java -Dname=eq_agent -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -server -Xmx2G -Xms256M -Xss384K -jar /eq/equalum/eqagent-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/lib/eql_agent-0.4.1.0-SNAPS
124895  2.0 2896252 0.2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -Dproc_namenode -Xmx1000m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/eq/hadoop/logs -D
125728  3.4 4788960 0.3 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -cp /eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Dsp
125831  2.3 4417984 0.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -cp /eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Dsp
125905  3.0 4833676 0.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -cp /eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Dsp
125986  3.6 4833952 0.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -cp /eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/eq/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Dsp
126254  1.7 2882876 0.1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -Dproc_datanode -Xmx1000m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/eq/hadoop/logs -D
126432  2.4 2858676 0.0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java -Dproc_secondarynamenode -Xmx1000m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/eq/hadoop
```

I am trying to get a specific java process but I get all java processes I am trying to get only a specific process. how can I change the command to do that?

Comment: add which specific process you want to question.

Comment: i want to monitor this process for example:

9067  3.7 5889540 15.7 java -Dname=eq_engine -Dlogback.configurationFile=/eq/equalum/eql-server-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/conf/engine_logback.xml -Xmx2G -Xms256M -Xss384K -server -Djava.security

Comment: You should try to find some uniqueness in this log and put a `grep` for that uniq string.

Answer (score 1):

once you have the pid (9067)

```
ps -p 9067 -o pid=,%mem=,vsz=,%cpu=,command=
```

EDIT as I just copied the command from question I didn't noticed there was many `=`, there can be only one `=` at the end, it is to remove header

```
ps -p 9067 -o pid,%mem,vsz,%cpu,command
ps -p 9067 -o pid,%mem,vsz,%cpu,command=
```

`man ps` for more information

Comment: i am getting this output:

ps -p 22124 -o pid=,%mem=,vsz=,%cpu=,command=
,%mem=,vsz=,%cpu=,command=
                     22124

Answer (score 0):

fast way - use grep:

```
ps -C java -o pid=,%mem=,vsz=,%cpu=,command= |grep S‌​NAPSHOT/conf/engine_‌​logback.xml
```

enjoy

Comment: I know but I am getting the following output:

 15952  0.7 4886812 0.0 java -Dname=eq_engine -Dlogback.configurationFile=/eq/equalum/eql-server-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/conf/engine_logback.xml -Xmx2G -Xms256M -Xss384K -server -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4455 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/ -cp /eq/equalum/eql-server-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/lib/org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j-

Comment: use pattern: S‌​NAPSHOT/conf/engine_‌​logback.xml